# JObject instance expected documentdb bulk insert

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a list which have calendar data for 3 years,i have them in excel so i used oledb to read data and store them in a list.You can find the list below

```
IList<BulkDateInsert> objExcelCon = ReadExcel(Filepath);
```

What i get in the above list

```
{
 "CalendarDate": "\/Date(1490985000000)\/",
 "Calendarday": "Sat",
  "isweekday": false,
  "isweekend": true
},
{
  "CalendarDate": "\/Date(1491071400000)\/",
  "Calendarday": "Sun",
  "isweekday": false,
  "isweekend": true
},
{
  "CalendarDate": "\/Date(1491157800000)\/",
  "Calendarday": "Mon",
  "isweekday": true,
  "isweekend": false
},
{
  "CalendarDate": "\/Date(1491244200000)\/",
  "Calendarday": "Tue",
  "isweekday": true,
  "isweekend": false
},
{
  "CalendarDate": "\/Date(1491330600000)\/",
  "Calendarday": "Wed",
  "isweekday": true,
  "isweekend": false
}, ..... N (upto year 2021)
```

I am using documentdb so i want the above list as a single document instead separate document for each day.

**I get this error when i try to use createdocumentasync()**

Object serialized to String. JObject instance expected.

```
 IList<BulkDateInsert> objExcelCon = ReadExcel(Filepath);
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        var json = js.Serialize(objExcelCon);
                        var ParsedJson = json.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty);

                        await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collection.SelfLink, ParsedJson);
```

Need them to be inserted as a single document so that it will be easier for me to query later.

Comment: No idea what you're doing with `json.Replace()` and no idea what your error is, but... you're making a mistake trying to load all (thousands?) of your calendar entries into a single document: It will eventually fail due to max doc size limitation. This is a well known "unbounded array" scenario. And it's *not* easier to query; it's exactly the opposite. And to even have such a repeating type of data in a document, it would need to be in an array (which means searching through an array for queries). I'd suggest taking some more time to read up on document stores and data modeling.

Comment: Not that I can possible dream of creating a data model for you (since that's a fairly open-ended discussion) but... you should start with the basic idea that every calendar entry is its own document (the opposite of your initial premise), and then go from there.

Comment: Thanks david yeah the size limit is 16kb.So it is better to insert each day as separate later get them all in a single list using c# ?

Answer (score 0):

> I get this error when i try to use createdocumentasync()
>   Object serialized to String. JObject instance expected.

Please don’t serialize a list object and pass it as document to [CreateDocumentAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentasync.aspx) to create a Document for storing 3 years calendar data. If possible, as David Makogon said, please create document for each calendar entry. Besides, you could also group calendar entries into batches and create separate document for grouped calendar entries. The following simple sample is for your reference.

```
class Program
{
    string EndpointUri = "{endpoint URL}";
    string PrimaryKey = "{primary key}";
    DocumentClient client;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BulkDateInsert item = new BulkDateInsert() { CalendarDate = @"\/Date(1490985000000)\/", Calendarday = "Sat", isweekday = false, isweekend = true };
        BulkDateInsert item1 = new BulkDateInsert() { CalendarDate = @"\/Date(1491071400000)\/", Calendarday = "Sun", isweekday = false, isweekend = true };
        List<BulkDateInsert> list = new List<BulkDateInsert>();
        list.Add(item);
        list.Add(item1);

        IList<BulkDateInsert> objExcelCon= list;

        GroupedData gdata = new GroupedData() { Calendardata = objExcelCon };

       Program p = new Program();

        p.CreateDocumentForCalendarData(gdata).Wait();
    }

    private async Task CreateDocumentForCalendarData(GroupedData ParsedJson)
    {
        this.client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);

        await client.CreateDocumentAsync("dbs/{dbname}/colls/{collectionname}", ParsedJson);
    }

public class GroupedData {

    //could be weekly, monthly data
        public IList<BulkDateInsert> Calendardata { get; set; }
    }

    public class BulkDateInsert
    {
        public string CalendarDate { get; set; }
        public string Calendarday { get; set; }
        public bool isweekday { get; set; }
        public bool isweekend { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what difference does the above method have when compared with looping ? Any performance improvement ?

Comment: So i did an excel insert of 1461 records using foreach with docdb emulator it takes around 20 secs for that insert alone @400RU's so wondering if i need to do bulk insert in millions then it would take more minutes to do that operation ?

Comment: so if i have 1000ru's/sec then that would be 200 writes/sec with 5ru for each 1kb size doc so thats around 12k per min.So let me know if my math is correct is this the way how pricing works ?

Comment: If the data consistency was configured at Session, and the indexing policy was set to None, **1kb size doc + 200 writes/second** would consume about 200*5=1000 RU/s. Besides, it’s necessary to take the [these variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-request-units) into consideration when estimating the number of request units to reserve for collection. And [request unit calculator](https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner) could help estimate the request unit requirements for operations.